# Differential equation with the Substitution method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this equation below :

$$ y' = \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + \frac{y}{x}  \tag 1 $$

The first step was to to substitute $\frac{y}{x}$ with $u$

=>   $ u = \frac{y}{x}$     => $y' = u'x + u \tag 2$

Then with
$(1) = (2)$,  I got at the end

$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\cos\left(y\right)+1\right)-\ln\left(1-\cos\left(y\right)\right)}{2} = \ln|x| + C$$

And after more simplification :
$$\frac{\cos(y)}{1-\cos(y)} = 2Cx   $$

How can I get the **general function** from this equation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your last line:
$$\frac{\cos(y)+1}{1-\cos(y)} = Cx^2$$
$$\cos(y)+1 = Cx^2(1- \cos y)$$
$$ \cos y (1+Cx^2)=Cx^2-1$$
$$ \cos y =\dfrac {Cx^2-1}{ Cx^2+1}$$
$$\implies y(x)=\cos^{-1} \left ( \dfrac {Cx^2-1}{ Cx^2+1} \right)$$

---

Or more simply:

$$u'x= \sin u$$
$$\int \dfrac {du}{\sin u}=\int \dfrac {dx}{x}$$
$$-\ln (\cot u/2)=\ln x +K$$
$$\cot \dfrac u 2=\dfrac C x$$
$$u=2 \cot ^{-1} \left ( \dfrac Cx \right)$$
$$\boxed {y(x)=2x \cot ^{-1} \left ( \dfrac Cx \right)}$$

---

For the integral note that:
$$I=\int \dfrac {dx}{\sin x }=\int \dfrac {dx}{2 \sin x/2 \cos x/2}$$
$$I=\int \dfrac 12\dfrac {\cos x/ 2dx}{\sin x/2 \cos ^2 x/2}$$
$$I=\int \dfrac {d \tan \dfrac x 2}{\tan \dfrac x2}=\ln \tan \dfrac x 2+C$$

Or you can use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)  
$$\int \dfrac {dx}{\sin x} =\int \dfrac {1+t^2}{2t}\dfrac {2dt}{1+t^2}
=\int \dfrac {dt}{t}=\ln t +C$$
Where $t=\tan \dfrac x 2$

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply . Quick question : is it obvious that the integral of 1/sin(x) is equal to ln|tan(x/2)| + C  ? Or should I show the steps that I did to reach that result  ?

Comment: @Gaston one possible solution to the integral is to notice that ${\frac{1}{\sin(x)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{1 - \cos^2(x)}}$. Could you take it from here?

Comment: Yes but the point here is whether it's necessary to show how to calculate the integral of 1/sin(x) ? (In an exam paper for example)

Comment: I added some lines for the integral .... @Gaston You can also use the solution posted in the vomment by Riemans

Answer (score 0):

There is an amazing manner for solving
$$y' = \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + \frac{y}{x}  $$
First use $y=x\,z$ to make
$$x\,z'=\sin(z)$$ Now, switch variables
$$\frac x {x'}=\sin(z) \implies \frac{x'}x=\csc(z)\implies \log(|x|)+c=\log \left(\tan \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)$$